# MySQL query returning errors

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get coordinates and locations from a database, but my server is returning this error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'long ) - radians(0) ) + sin( radians(0) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distanc' 
 at line 1

Query: 
SELECT id, 
    address, 
    name, 
    (3959 * acos(cos(radians(0)) * 
           cos(radians(lat)) * 
           cos(radians(long) - radians(0)) + 
           sin(radians(0)) * 
           sin(radians(lat)))
    ) AS distance 
FROM places 
HAVING distance < 10 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Do I have to escape "lat" and "long" with `, or is that formula wrong altogether? Thanks.

Also, the coordinates I'm using are 0, 0 (just for test purposes).

Comment: Why are you using radians(0), since that's just zero?  Regardless, I was able to get the parenthesized part to run correctly.

Comment: Those are the test coordinates I chose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LONG is a reserved word in mysql. Escape it using backticks when using it as a column name.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I forgot to escape something. :P

Answer (score 1):

Replace the HAVING statement with "WHERE" statement. There is no "GROUP BY", then why are you using HAVING?

Comment: MySQL lets you use `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html: "*The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well."* I expect he/she is doing it because `distance` is a derived column name. Whether it's a *good idea*...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra `)`. Try this

```
SELECT id, address, name, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(0) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( long ) - radians(0) ) + sin( radians(0) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) AS distance FROM places HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```